# wp7 and dependency property : onChanged and onRead?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

well I want build a wp7 control,so I write it and all go well, but the problem is that I can intercept on write(see onItemsSourcePropertyChanged)but not on read I would like explain better:

```
public static readonly
DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty=
         DependencyProperty.Register(
             "ItemsSource",
             typeof(ObservableCollection<ObjWithDesc>),
             typeof(HorizontalListBox),
             new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)
         );




    static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
         ((HorizontalListBox) obj).OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(e);
}
```

OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged is called when I use SetValue(dp,..) but there isn't onItemsSourcePropertyRead ? that is called when I Use GetValue()? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the OnRead action to the getter of the backing field:

```
    public string ItemsSource
    {
        get 
        { 
            // Call your OnRead functionality here!
            return (string)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); 
        }

        set 
        { 
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but it works with xaml like <ElistBox itemsource="{bind ...}?

Comment: @user233150 can you post a complete example of what you're trying to do